# Using angular for web developpment, error "No overload matches this call"

Tags: angular

Executing this code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/service/product.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  products: any[] = [];

  constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.productService.getAllProducts().subscribe((prods: {count: Number, products: any[]}) => {
      this.products = prods.products;
    });
  }

}
```

I get this error :

```
Error: src/app/component/home/home.component.ts:16:54 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 5, '(observer?: NextObserver<Object> | ErrorObserver<Object> | CompletionObserver<Object> | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(prods: {    count: Number;    products: any[];}) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NextObserver<Object> | ErrorObserver<Object> | CompletionObserver<Object> | undefined'.
      Property 'complete' is missing in type '(prods: {    count: Number;    products: any[];}) => void' but required in type 'CompletionObserver<Object>'.
  Overload 2 of 5, '(next?: ((value: Object) => void) | undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(prods: {    count: Number;    products: any[];}) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'prods' and 'value' are incompatible.
        The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
          Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type '{ count: Number; products: any[]; }': count, products

16       this.productService.getAllProducts().subscribe((prods: {count: Number, products: any[]}) => {
                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts:64:5
    64     complete: () => void;
           ~~~~~~~~
    'complete' is declared here.
```

Comment: I've the same issue

Comment: show code productService.getAllProducts()

Comment: here it is `import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {

  private SERVER_URL = environment.SERVER_URL;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getAllProducts(numberResults=10){
     return this.http.get(this.SERVER_URL + '/products',{
      params: {
        limit: numberResults.toString()
      }
     });
  }
}

`

Comment: You can edit the question and simply post the function to it. That way it is much more readable then in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
      getAllProducts( numberOfResults = 10) {
  return this.http.get<any>(this.SERVER_URL + '/products', {
    params: {
      limit: numberOfResults.toString()
    }
  });
```